# Assign values based on multiple columns with several criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

The picture below is the sample of my data structure and expected result. I need to create a new column based on several criteria.

1. For each `subject`, assign `Per_size` of `CS+` to the new column, and only update value when there is a new `CS+`.
2. Use the `Per_size` of the first `CS+` before the first CS+

Thank you very much for your helps!

[image]

```
structure(list(subject = c("subject1", "subject1", "subject1", 
"subject1", "subject1", "subject1", "subject1", "subject1", "subject1", 
"subject2", "subject2", "subject2", "subject2", "subject2", "subject2", 
"subject2", "subject2", "subject2"), stimulus = c("CS-", "CS-", 
"CS+", "CS-", "S8", "S7", "S2", "CS+", "CS+", "CS-", "CS-", "CS+", 
"S4", "S9", "S7", "CS+", "CS+", "S8"), Per_size = c(60L, 70L, 
30L, 85L, 62L, 56L, 42L, 36L, 34L, 24L, 21L, 70L, 65L, 31L, 35L, 
79L, 79L, 34L)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` methods for the `data.table` input, create the 'New' as 'Per_size' by specifying the `i` with a logical condition.  Then, use `nafill` to replace the NA in forward and backward direction grouped by 'subject'

```
library(data.table)
df1[stimulus == 'CS+', New := Per_size]
df1[, New  := nafill(nafill(New, type = 'locf'), type = 'nocb'), subject]
```

-output

```
df1
     subject stimulus Per_size New
 1: subject1      CS-       60  30
 2: subject1      CS-       70  30
 3: subject1      CS+       30  30
 4: subject1      CS-       85  30
 5: subject1       S8       62  30
 6: subject1       S7       56  30
 7: subject1       S2       42  30
 8: subject1      CS+       36  36
 9: subject1      CS+       34  34
10: subject2      CS-       24  70
11: subject2      CS-       21  70
12: subject2      CS+       70  70
13: subject2       S4       65  70
14: subject2       S9       31  70
15: subject2       S7       35  70
16: subject2      CS+       79  79
17: subject2      CS+       79  79
18: subject2       S8       34  79
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(result = if_else(stimulus == "CS+", Per_size, NA_integer_)) %>%
  fill(result, .direction = "downup")
# # A tibble: 18 x 4
# # Groups:   subject [2]
#    subject  stimulus Per_size result
#    <chr>    <chr>       <int>  <int>
#  1 subject1 CS-            60     30
#  2 subject1 CS-            70     30
#  3 subject1 CS+            30     30
#  4 subject1 CS-            85     30
#  5 subject1 S8             62     30
#  6 subject1 S7             56     30
#  7 subject1 S2             42     30
#  8 subject1 CS+            36     36
#  9 subject1 CS+            34     34
#  ...
```